# Mapping of user Id's

Tags: podman

I'm evaluating podman in rootless mode and faceing an issue with the User ID Mapping.

I run podman with "myuser" who has the ID 1000.

```
cat /etc/subuid
myuser:100000:65536
```

When running a pod, where the pod user is root, the created files on the mounted volume belongs to "myuser" from host perspective, I can access them and so everything is fine.

When running a pod, where the **pod user is not root**, for example UID 2002, the created files on the mounted volume belongs to UID "102002" from host perspective which results in the situation, that **I can not access that files on the host**.

As expected, podman unshare looks like following

```
podman unshare cat /proc/self/uid_map
0       1000          1
1     100000      65536
```

Is there any chance, that I can get access to this files by correct configuration of the podman run or config files?

Thanks
Joerg

Comment: Creating a file running as UID _2002_ in the container would normally create a file with ownership UID _102001_ on the host, if the _/etc/subuid_ contains _myuser:100000:65536_. Are you maybe using _--userns_ somehow?

Comment: I had a [related issue](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#9-newuidmap-missing-when-running-rootless-podman-commands) on Ubuntu 20.05, fixed installing `uidmap` package

Answer (score 20):

##### Update 4 November 2022

[Podman 4.3.0](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v4.3.0) introduced the options *uid* and *gid* that can be given to `--userns keep-id`.

The UID and GID mapping that is described with **--uidmap** and **--gidmap** in this answer can now be given as  `--userns keep-id:uid=$uid,gid=$gid` instead. The only difference is that the new syntax is shorter and thus saves you some keyboard typing.

See also the troubleshooting tip:

[Podman run fails with "Error: unrecognized namespace mode keep-id:uid=1000,gid=1000 passed"](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#39-podman-run-fails-with-error-unrecognized-namespace-mode-keep-iduid1000gid1000-passed)

---

Yes, you can remap UIDs by using the command-line option
[--uidmap](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html#uidmap-container-uid-from-uid-amount).

It looks like the container UID you are using is

```
102002-100000+1=2003
```

The digit 1 is there because the normal UID on the host is mapped to root in the container by default.

This example demonstrates such a calculation (1002002-100000+1=2003)

```
$ id  -un
testuser
$ grep testuser /etc/subuid
testuser:100000:65536
$ grep testuser /etc/subgid
testuser:100000:65536
$ mkdir dir1
$ chmod 777 dir1
$ podman run --rm -v ./dir1:/dir1:Z \
             --user 2003:2003 \
             docker.io/library/ubuntu touch /dir1/a
$ ls -l dir1/a
-rw-r--r--. 1 102002 102002 0 Jan 19 19:35 dir1/a
$
```

Let's define some variables so that this Stackoverflow answer can be more reusable for others.

```
uid=2003
subuidStart=100000
subuidSize=65536
```

You could try passing these three options at the same time to `podman run`

- `--uidmap $uid:0:1`
- `--uidmap 0:1:$uid`
- `--uidmap $(($uid+1)):$(($uid+1)):$(($subuidSize-$uid))`

Note `$(( expression ))` is Bash syntax so you need to use a bash shell.

#### --uidmap $uid:0:1

Map the UID *$uid* in the container to your normal UID on the host.

| host UID | intermediate UID | container UID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| normal host UID | 0 | $uid |

#### --uidmap 0:1:$uid

Map the UIDs between *0* and *$uid - 1*  in the container to the lower part of the subuids (subordinate UIDs) (from *$subuidStart* to *$subuidStart+$uid-1*).

| host UID | intermediate UID | container UID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $subuidStart | 1 | 0 |
| $subuidStart + 1 | 2 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| $subuidStart + $uid - 1 | $uid | $uid - 1 |

#### --uidmap $(($uid+1)):$(($uid+1)):$(($subuidSize-$uid))

Map the UIDs between *$uid+1* and *$subuidSize* in the container to the remaining subuids.

| host UID | intermediate UID | container UID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $subuidStart + $uid | $uid + 1 | $uid + 1 |
| $subuidStart + $uid + 1 | $uid + 2 | $uid + 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| $subuidStart + $subuidSize - 1 | $subuidSize | $subuidSize |

Note that the mapping between host UIDs and the intermediate UIDs can't be modified by the user. The normal host UID is always mapped to the intermediate UID *0*.

Note that in the general case there might be more than one range of subuids.

There is a similar command-line option **--gidmap** for GIDs.

##### Update 2022-02-14

I wrote a [troubleshooting tip](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#33-container-creates-a-file-that-is-not-owned-by-the-users-regular-uid) about this in the Podman documentation.

Comment: I have created a script with that --uidmap logic.
I received fort the error "Error: Container ID 0 cannot be mapped to a host ID" so I have added "--uidmap=0:1:1" as an additional parameter.

Now I receive
```Error: error creating container storage: error creating an ID-mapped copy of layer "1cfdca7e59023298ba1f7787a961bd90e2bcac6680d9591268d2d1c83c0c8ef7": exit status 1: error during chown: error mapping container ID pair idtools.IDPair{UID:0, GID:42} for "etc/gshadow" to host: Container ID 42 cannot be mapped to a host ID
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do the same for `podman build`? I tried replacing `--uidmap` with `--userns-uid-map`, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I've never tried `podman build` with `--userns-uid-map` but I would guess that it  does the same thing as `--uidmap` for `podman run`.

Comment: I have the same problem. While for `podman run` the option is clear, i can't figure out what could be a valid value for `containerUID` since a new container will be created for the build of the image. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Using `--userns=keep-id` is an easy alternative solution compared to using the complex mapping of uidmap/gidmap.

https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html

Answer (score 1):

As User muzammil already pointed out, using option `--userns=keep-id` is a simple and effective way to solve the issue.

Assume there is user 999 inside container that needs access to the mounted volume, then you will probably want to run podman with option:

```
--userns=keep-id:uid=999
```